# Bootstrap Carousel works in isolation but not on my webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel on my homepage for my website but the previous/next buttons and the indicators don't work.

However, if I snip out the piece of code for carousel, It works perfectly fine on a page that only has the carousel on it.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Jquery CDN -->
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"   integrity="sha256-4/zUCqiq0kqxhZIyp4G0Gk+AOtCJsY1TA00k5ClsZYE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
  <!-- logo -->

  <div>
     <p class = "logochinese">
     <a class = "logo" href="index.html">
        <img src="logo.jpg" width="117" height="100">
     </a>登峰国际教育
     </p>

  </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default center">
        <div class="container-fluid">



           <!--Menu-->
           <div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Partnership</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
     </nav>
    <!-- Indicators for carousel -->

    <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
       </ol>

      <!--Wrapper for slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/test1.jpg" alt="test1">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h3>Schools</h3>
               <p>Schools caption</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
             <img src="img/test2.jpg" alt="test2">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Highschool</h3>
                <p>Secondary School</p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
             <img src="img/test3.jpg" alt="test3">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Students</h3>
                <p>High school students</p>
             </div>
          </div>


          <div class="item">
             <img src="img/test4.jpg" alt="test4">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Students</h3>
                <p>Elementary school students</p>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      <!--Left/Right controls-->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

When I try to press the left or right arrow for the carousel, the webpage jumps to where my carousel is and appends #myCarousel2 to the end of the url.

It seems as to interpret the buttons as an anchor tag.  I have tried replacing the href attribute in the `<a>` tag with data-target but no luck.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you loading in the JS files properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add `jquery.js` file before `bootstrap.min.js` file like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Because there is no mistake in your carousel code. It is almost the same with this [carousel example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, it works perfectly now.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You called your scripts in header are also you called Bootstarp js first but you should call jQuery first. Because jQuery required to work Bootstrap js.

Called all your scripts in footer area and call jQuery first 
just like this one

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the logic to give the same answer, which has been given before?

Comment: Because When I wrote and post the answer I didn't notice you give the same answer. When I notice I give you upvote also. But I think you gave a minus one that's not okay

Comment: Upvote system exists if some supports your answer or question. If you have the same idea with someone, you can upvote the answer but there is no need to give the same answer again and again.

Comment: Man you should read my comments carefully. I said that I didn't notice that you gave the same answer. Also your answer and mine are not same because You just said call jQuery before bootstrap js. but you didn't show the reason why he should call jQuery first. I did